# php extension code must be c89 style

Tags: c, c99, c89

I wrote a php extension: https://github.com/binpack/binpack-php, it works great and I want to submit this extension to [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/).

But they said that my code is C99 style and PHP except C89 style. I read somethings about [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and [C89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C89_%28C_version%29#C99).

And figure out some difference:

- `stdbool.h`
- `inline` vs `__inline__`

I think there are some problem in these 2 files:

- https://github.com/binpack/binpack-php/blob/master/bin_pack.c
- https://github.com/binpack/binpack-php/blob/master/bin_pack.h

I modified some of my code and used `-std=gnu89` to test them. But I am not sure if there are still some problems.

**My question is**:

- How can I test if my code is c89 style?
- If anyone can point out the problems in my code, that will be great.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this question is more suited for codereview.com.

Comment: Probably the single biggest difference between C89 and C99 is that in C89 all variable declarations must be at the top of the enclosing scope - anywhere else is not permitted. It looks like you still have many violations of that in `bin_pack.c`. Another thing, you should not be making identifiers that start with `_` - that is a privilege reserved for the compiler.

Comment: Not `inline` vs `__inline__` but `inline` vs nothing-at-all.

Comment: @R.. Yes, you are right. But I do not understand why the gcc support `__inline__`  for ISO c. I read this:  `If you are writing a header file to be included in ISO C programs, write __inline__ instead of inline` in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: @srain: As usual the GCC manual makes no sense the way it's worded. What they mean is that, if your header is being included when *using GCC* in C89 conformance mode, where `inline` is not a keyword but reserved for use by the application, you can still use `__inline__` to get at the desired behavior. However this is then not an "ISO C program" but a "GNU C program" using a particular namespace-conformance profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't warn about every feature not in C89, but

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c89 ...
```

is a good place to start.

Comment: Minor pedantry: `-std=c89` / `-std=c++98` are synonymous with `-ansi`, and `-ansi` looks a bit cleaner when doing strict checking against K&R v2 (i.e. C89/90).

Comment: `-ansi` is a misnomer, so it's better to use `-std=c89` which means what it looks like.